# Returned values from function as class attributes

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameter-passing

Say I have a function and a class like this,

```
>>> def something():
...     x = 5 
...     y = 6
...     return x, y

>>> class SomethingElse():
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             self.x = x
...             self.y = y
...             print(x+y)
...
```

I want to pass what my function returns as attributes to my class, is this possible to do? Since I when I call my function I get it as only 1 attribute.

```
>>> S = SomethingElse(5, 6)
11
>>> S1 = SomethingElse(something)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What I actually want is,

```
>>> S1 = SomethingElse(something)
11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the splat (*or "unpacking"*) operator `*`, like so

```
>>> SomethingElse(*something())
11
```

This can be seen in [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial, and is usually referred to as argument unpacking.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options.

This **makes `y` an optional argument.** Call it using `SomethingElse(something())` or `SomethingElse(5, 6)`.

```
class SomethingElse():
     def __init__(self, x, y=None):
         if y is None:
             x, y = *x
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         print(x + y)
```

This **defines a helper function `make_kind` that returns a new instance of `SomethingElse`** entirely. You can call it using `SomethingElse.make_kind()`; no `self` paremeter is needed.

```
class SomethingElse():
     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         print(x + y)

     @staticmethod
     def make_kind():  
          x = 5 
          y = 6
          return SomethingElse.__init__(x, y)
```

Learn more about [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#staticmethod) on the official Python 3.5 Docs.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not? Just "I don't think this really addresses the question at all" is not helpful.

Comment: The question is how to pass a tuple to a constructor. Your first option really makes no sense and should be replaced by the use of a splat operator. Your second option makes assumptions about the design - it may be a valid solution, but again, doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: I will stick with the first answer, unpacking the list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think that was obvious in the question. My first option uses an optional parameter to create the effect of operator overloading.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ operator overloading? How so? And why is that a good thing? I'm pretty sure it is a SyntaxError anyway. And using it like`SomethingElse(something) ` is *definitely* wrong, since `something` is a function object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 1. it is not 2. typo'd

Comment: I'm still not understanding you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga look, it's like function overloading from other languages.

Comment: This sort of assumes that the OP indeed wants to have an overloaded "constructor" for his class, I think is juanpa's point. For all we know, this function isn't intended on being a constructor overload. As for your answer with `staticmethod`, I think using a `classmethod` and returning `cls()` would be a bit better.

Comment: @Mitch Who knows, that could have been what the OP wanted.

Comment: I'm just saying, it is a bit of an odd assumption to make. And were that the case, you ought to use a classmethod as opposed to a staticmethod and somewhat contrived call as you have done.